# Regex Optionally match a pattern multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I want to match a specific pattern optionally as many times as may occur.

My String
    
`0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 23 83 90 $595 NO IDL`

After `45` until `$595` There could be upto 6 more number there. How can I optionally look for repeating number in that space?

Here's what I have so far:

```
/([\d.]+) ([\d.]+) ([\d.]+)? (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)  \$(\d+)/ig
```

Here are some samples with expected outputs:

```
0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 23 83 90 $595 NO IDL
output: array([0] => 0.91, 
              [1] => 0.45, 
              [2] => 0.69, 
              [3] => 58, 
              [4] => 47, 
              [5] => 45, 
              [6] => 23, 
              [7] => 83, 
              [8] => 90, 
              [9] => 595)

0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL
output: array([0] => 0.91, 
              [1] => 0.45, 
              [2] => 0.69, 
              [3] => 58, 
              [4] => 47, 
              [5] => 45,  
              [5] => 595)

0.91 0.45 0.69 0.63 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL
output: Does not match the pattern because we only want 3 of the first items to contain decimals.
```

This seems to split the last number into multiple numbers. Can't figure out whats going on.

I am using php preg_match method for this so would like not empty elements in the resulting array if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Could you do something like /([\S]+)/ig? That would split up your entire string into an array.

Comment: Could you please explain what output you expect for a couple of sample strings? Probably, you may also get all these numbers from the start of string only with [`preg_match_all('~\G\s*\$?\K\d[\d.]*~', $s, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/tBEaph/1), but it is not that clear.

Comment: You could try [`(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)?){5}\s*|\G(\d+(\.\d+)?) `](https://regex101.com/r/azLdIf/1). Then the numbers after 45 and before $595 are captured in group 1.

Comment: I suggest validating the string before extracting the numbers from the beginning of the string. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50860510/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may validate the string with a positive lookahead triggered at the start of the string, and then match all numbers from the start up to the currency value once the validation succeeds:

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+ \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: \d+)* \$\d))\s*\$?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tDMPgK/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+ \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: \d+)* \$\d))` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or start of a string (`^`) that is followed with

  - `\d+\.\d+`
  - - a space
  - `\d+\.\d+`
  - - a space
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional fractional part
  - `(?: \d+)*` - 0+ sequences of a space followed with 1+ digits
  - - space
  - `\$\d` - a `$` and a digit.
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\$?` - an optional `$` char
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - an int/float number (1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/FUoosv):

```
$strs = ['0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 23 83 90 $595 NO IDL','0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL','0.91 0.45 0.69 0.63 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL'];
$rx = '~(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+ \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: \d+)* \$\d))\s*\$?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?~';
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    echo "$s:\n";
    if (preg_match_all($rx, $s, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches[0]);
        echo "---------\n";
    } else {
        echo "NO MATCH!!!\n---------\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 23 83 90 $595 NO IDL:
Array
(
    [0] => 0.91
    [1] => 0.45
    [2] => 0.69
    [3] => 58
    [4] => 47
    [5] => 45
    [6] => 23
    [7] => 83
    [8] => 90
    [9] => 595
)
---------
0.91 0.45 0.69 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL:
Array
(
    [0] => 0.91
    [1] => 0.45
    [2] => 0.69
    [3] => 58
    [4] => 47
    [5] => 45
    [6] => 595
)
---------
0.91 0.45 0.69 0.63 58 47 45 $595 NO IDL:
NO MATCH!!!
---------
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected results:

```
/([\d\$.]+)/ig
```

Comment: I still need to match that specific pattern. I can have an extra item in the beginning with decimal places. So 3 of the first numbers must contain decimal places and if a fourth appears with decimals it no longer matches.

Answer (score 0):

You might repeat the amount of numbers until you matched `45` which is the 6th number.

**Explanation**

- `(?:\d+\.\d+)(?: \d+\.\d+){2}` Match the number at the start (digit with an decimal part) 3 times
- `(?: \d+){3}` Match a digit with a whitespace 3 times. That will match up till 45
- `\s*` Match zero or more whitespace characters
- `|` Or
- `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match using a negative lookahead to assert not start of the string
- `(\d+)\s` Capture the digits and match the whitespace in a capturing group

`(?:\d+\.\d+)(?: \d+\.\d+){2}(?: \d+){3}\s*|\G(?!^)(\d+)\s`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VfmC44/1)

For example a demo to extract the 3 digits after 45:

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8aK4o)